# Add dynamic variables to an url

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I would like to add dynamic variables to an url example:

```
QNetworkRequest req( QUrl( QString("http://website.com/?test=1&id=1") ) );
```

But when i try this:

```
// the HTTP request
varUrl = "http://website.com/?test=";
varUrl += info;
varUrl += "&id=";
varUrl += info_2;

QNetworkRequest req( QUrl( QString(varUrl) ) );
QNetworkReply *reply = mgr.get(req);
eventLoop.exec(); // blocks stack until "finished()" has been called
```

i get this error:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message you posted is partly unrelated. Your actual problem is this:

```
QNetworkRequest req( QUrl( QString(varUrl) ) );
```

This is treated as a function declaration. This is a corner case in C++ and it's commonly referred to as the "most vexing parse". See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse for an explanation.

In any event, use the `QUrl::fromUserInput()` static function instead of passing the query string directly. This will encode the query correctly (otherwise you'd need to manually encode the query correctly by hand.) So in short, change the above line to:

```
QNetworkRequest req(QUrl::fromUserInput(varUrl));
```

This also fixes the parsing issue; the above is treated correctly like a variable definition, not a function declaration, and your code should now compile fine.

As a side-note, you can use the `QString::arg()` function to construct your string in one go, without having to use append (`+=`) operations. So you can construct your URL string like this:

```
varUrl = QString("http://website.com/?test=%1&id=%2").arg(info).arg(info_2);
```

`%1` will be replaced with the contents of `info`, and `%2` with the contents of `info_2`.

Comment: Modern solution to vexing parse: `QUrl { QString { varUrl } }`.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qurlquery.html):

> The QUrlQuery class provides a way to manipulate a key-value pairs in
> a URL's query.
>
> It is used to parse the query strings found in URLs like the
> following:
>
> [image]

Posible solution is to use `QUrlQuery`:

```
QString info = "1";
QString info_2 = "1";
QUrl url("http://website.com/");
QUrlQuery query;
query.addQueryItem("test", info);
query.addQueryItem("id", info_2);
url.setQuery(query);
```

Comment: That's a much better approach. Encoding these things can be a total pain.

Comment: @tadman You can also use the `QUrl::fromUserInput()` static function to encode an input correctly.

Comment: Yes, it is also an option but seeing the code of how the author built his url I think this is a better option.